# convert command curl to php

Tags: php, post, curl

**Hi all**! I have curl command (audio file upload):

```
curl -k -v -H "Expect: " -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary  '@/Path/To/File/test.wav' -X POST  'https://myapi.com?param1=xxx&param2=yyy'
```

File successfully uploaded and readable. But when I used php script:

```
$filename = 'test.wav';
$file = '@/Path/To/File/test.wav';

$post_url = "https://someapi.com?param1=xxx&param2=yyy";
$post_str = array("$filename" => $file);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/octet-stream'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect: '));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$http_body = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($http_body);
```

File successfully uploaded and test.wav is not valid (with some error). What am I doing wrong in the script?

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: stream format is not wav

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the issue is these lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/octet-stream'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect: '));
```

The second call will remove the "Content-Type" Header. Try consolidating these:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type:application/octet-stream','Expect: ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'test.wav';
$file = '/Path/To/File/test.wav';

$post_url = "https://someapi.com?param1=xxx&param2=yyy";
$post_str = file_get_contents($file);
$headers = array('Content-Type:application/octet-stream', 'Expect: ');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen("/Path/to/header.txt", "w+"));
$http_body = curl_exec($ch);
```

It's work perfect. I solved the problem myself. File upload to the server binary. Thank you all!